# Which sentence is corect to use and why?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

**This is from a recent article:**

> He was rushed to the hospital immediately and a battery of tests **was**
>   conducted.

or

> He was rushed to the hospital immediately and a battery of tests **were**
>   conducted.

Which is correct and why is it correct? :)

Comment: Is it a trick question? :)

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is an exact duplicate of [the same question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226075/a-battery-of-tests-is-are).

Answer (score 4):

Good question.

The correct one is...

> He was rushed to the hospital immediately and a battery of tests ***was conducted.***

That's because we use it that way. The phrase shows a 'collective noun' and thus, the 'number of tests' doesn't affect it. Said that, the verb applies to 'a battery'.

Check out what [Cambrigde Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/battery) comes up in its example:

> *"In the kitchen an impressive **battery of** stainless steel utensils **hangs** on the wall."*

I also note that over the period of times, the singular 'verb' has grown in use. I mean if you use singular verb, it's *not incorrect!*.

Comment: You liar http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226075/which-is-correct-past-tense-plural/226088#226088

Comment: @Tay - Be careful. That comment is [not nice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). Moreover, crossposting questions on both sites is [highly discouraged](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/838/is-it-ok-to-cross-post-questions/839#839); [pick where you want to get your answer](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722), and ask it only once (or else tailor the question for each site).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on if you're using British English or American English.

AS I UNDERSTAND IT, in British English, a noun for a *collection of plural things* is considered plural. In American English, it is considered singular.

Since "a battery of tests" is "a collection of many tests" -- a singular noun that encompasses plural nouns (other examples would be "a herd of cows," "a flock of birds," "the Senate," etc.), it will have a different verb depending on whether you're speaking British or American.

In British English, it's "A battery...were". (Or "A herd...were" or "The American Senate were..." etc.)

In American English, it's "A battery...was." (Or "A herd...was," or "The Senate was..." etc.)

That said, because of the "of tests," many Americans would easily accept "were" there. This mostly shows up when the collective-noun (flock, herd, Senate) is being used alone: "The herd move/moves through the field. The flock eat/eats corn. The Senate was/were fillibustering."